# Grep's "Invalid range end" ­— bug or feature?

Tags: regex, grep, gnu

I've got these three files:

```
$ cat pattern-ok 
['\-]
$ cat pattern-buggy 
[\-']
$ cat text 
abc'def-ghi
```

And now, is the following a bug or a regexp feature I don't know?

```
$ cat text | grep -f pattern-ok 
abc'def-ghi
$ cat text | grep -f pattern-buggy
grep: Invalid range end
```

I'm using:

```
$ grep --version | head -n 1
grep (GNU grep) 2.20
```

Comment: Found this via Google; turns out sometimes this error is unexpectedly caused due to a glibc bug. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=583011

Comment: I got this because I'd written `[A-z0-9a-z]` and grep was right (the first z should be uppercase)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is because you are using the hyphen within other characters, so that `grep` understands it as a range, which happens to be invalid.

You are basically doing

```
grep "[\-']" file
```

This is interpreted by `grep` as you providing a range of characters to be checked on, like for example `grep "[a-z]" file`. But the range from `\` to `'` is invalid, hence the error.

And why the other one is working? You may be asking yourself. Because what you are doing is:

```
grep "['\-]" file
```

In this case you are looking for either the character `'`, `\` or `-` in the file.

See another example of it, where I want to find characters `a`, `-` or `3` in a given string:

```
$ echo "23-2" | grep -o '[a-3]'
grep: Invalid range end
$ echo "23-2" | grep -o '[a3-]'
3
-
$ echo "23-2" | grep -o '[a3\-]'
3
-
```

So the underlying problem is that you are using an expression `some character` + `-` + `another character` within a `[]` block and it tries to be read as the range of characters between `some character` and `another character`.

---

### How can you solve it?

If you want to match the character `-`, among others, just add it in the edges of the expression: as the first or last item.

From `man grep`:

> **Character Classes and Bracket Expressions**
>
> A bracket expression is a list of characters enclosed by [ and ].  It
>   matches any single character in that list;  if  the first  character 
>   of  the  list  is  the caret ^ then it matches any character not in
>   the list.  For example, the regular expression [0123456789] matches
>   any single digit.
>
> Within a bracket expression, **a range expression consists of two
>   characters separated by a hyphen**.  It matches any  single character
>   that sorts between the two characters, inclusive, using the locale's
>   collating sequence and character set.  For example, in the default C
>   locale, [a-d] is equivalent to [abcd].  Many locales sort characters
>   in dictionary  order,  and in  these  locales  [a-d]  is  typically 
>   not equivalent to [abcd]; it might be equivalent to [aBbCcDd], for
>   example.  To obtain the traditional interpretation of bracket
>   expressions, you can use the C locale by setting the LC_ALL 
>   environment variable to the value C.
>
> Finally, certain named classes of characters are predefined within
>   bracket expressions, as follows.  Their names are self explanatory,
>   and they are  [:alnum:],  [:alpha:],  [:cntrl:],  [:digit:], 
>   [:graph:],  [:lower:],  [:print:],  [:punct:], [:space:],  [:upper:], 
>   and [:xdigit:].  For example, [[:alnum:]] means the character class of
>   numbers and letters in the current locale. In the C locale and ASCII
>   character set encoding, this is  the  same  as  [0-9A-Za-z].   (Note 
>   that  the brackets in these class names are part of the symbolic
>   names, and must be included in addition to the brackets delimiting the
>   bracket expression.)  Most meta-characters lose their special meaning 
>   inside  bracket  expressions.   To  include  a literal  ]  place  it 
>   first  in  the  list.  Similarly, to include a literal ^ place it
>   anywhere but first.  **Finally, to include a literal - place it
>   last.**

Comment: So how do I escape the `-` to be treated as a normal character? Is putting it at the end of `[]` group the only way?

Comment: Yes, this will solve it. You can use `-` in the front or the back of the expression, so that it won't be treated as a range.

Comment: So there's *no way* to just escape it and put anywhere in the `[]` group? :O Pretty weird. For all my life I've been using it like `[abc\-def]` and didn't know the real meaning. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty weird indeed. I just added to the answer a reference in `man grep` where it exactly states this.

Comment: specifically, the range from "backslash" to "single quote" is 
invalid because the ASCII code for "backslash" is *greater than* than
 that of "single quote". The range `a-z` is OK because a is *smaller* than z, ASCII-wise.

Answer (score 13):

To avoid range value You can use `fgrep`.

Comment: I used this solution because I was parsing an array of file paths.

Comment: nice, useful when you only want to grep the string as a whole