# Grep for specific php malware pattern

Tags: shell, debugging, ssh, command-line, grep

I am trying to figure out grep for malware that is hard to match with a single pattern. One line from the malicious file looks like this:

```
$bhbwjhu[11].$bhbwjhu[15].$bhbwjhu[34].$bhbwjhu[23].$bhbwjhu[30].$bhbwjhu[6].$bhbwjhu[3].$bhbwjhu[34].$bhbwjhu[31]
```

Tried with something like this, but obviously, my grep skills are quite poor (this gives invalid range end error):

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -s -l "\$[A-z]*\[[0-9]*\]\.\$[A-z]*\[[0-9]*\]\.\$[A-z]*\[[0-9]*\]"
```

Any way to search for that bunch of array elements in files?

Grep version is

> grep (GNU grep) 2.20
>
> Linux version 2.6.32-896.16.1.lve1.4.54.el6.x86_64

Comment: Tried this and it worked without issue; maybe add your version of grep/platform.

Comment: @l'L'l yes, thank you, I have added that info

Comment: I guess grep is complaining about your usage of `[A-z]`, which indeed - depending on the locale - might raise an incorrect range. It doesn't make much sense anyway. Replace it either by `[A-Za-z]`, or follow the suggestion posted by JGK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the following:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -s -l '\$[[:alpha:]]*\[[[:digit:]]*\]\.\$[[:alpha:]]*\[[[:digit:]]*\]\.\$[[:alpha:]]*\[[[:digit:]]*\]'
```

Using the character classes is much more safer, than using ranges. Also I recommend using `-print0` and `xargs -0` so filenames with whitespaces don't mess your command up. See also this [explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754181/greps-invalid-range-end-bug-or-feature).

Comment: That did the trick, and I learned something new today, thanks!